# syntax error, unexpected '$alert' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, mysql

hmm i d'ont understand why I have this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$alert' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\envMailAuto\controler.php on line 19
```

**my controler:**

```
include 'modele.php';

$email=$_REQUEST["email2"];
if(isset($_REQUEST["check"])) echo $email;
else echo "omged";
$idarticle = 3555;

$DB_host     = "localhost";
   $DB_select   = "envmail";
   $DB_login    = "root";
   $DB_pass     = '';

$connection=mysql_connect($DB_host,$DB_login,$DB_pass); 

$db=mysql_select_db($DB_select, $conn);


alertarticleDAO $alert = new __alertarticle($connection);
```

my model:

```
Class alertarticleDAO {

var $connection;

public function __alertarticle($mysqlconnection){
$this->connection = $mysqlconnection;
}

public function insert($Idarticle,$email){
$query=" INSERT INTO envmail ( mail_env , id_article , actif )
VALUES ( $Idarticle , $email , 1)";

mysql_query($query,$this->connection);

}


}
```

Comment: Side note: `mysql_*` functions are becoming deprecated and will be removed from future versions of PHP. If you write new code use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead. They also provide options to protect you from SQL injections, which the `mysql_*` functions lack. Look for prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you don't need to specify the type when you initialize an object. Change this line:

```
alertarticleDAO $alert = new __alertarticle($connection);
```

into this:

```
$alert = new alertarticle($connection);
```

and the constructor definition is also wrong, change this:

```
public function __alertarticle($mysqlconnection){
```

into this:

```
function __construct($mysqlconnection){
```

Comment: Feel free to mark it as an answer, if that was enough for you of course. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the invalid keyword `alertarticleDAO`. In PHP you don't "set" the type of the variable like that.

But your "constructor" is not quite right, either you name it exactly like the class name or you name it `__construct()`.

So, your Constructor should look like this:

```
function __construct($mysqlconnection) { ... }
```

Instanciate it:

```
$alert = new alertarticleDAO($connection);
```